# Admin permission for creating blogs in multisite

Tags: multisite, user-roles

How can I do that ?
I have some blogs and anyone can register and build a new blog . I'd like to limit them just to visit and comment not to build a new blog unless I allow them .

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! :)
There is a setting on `wp-admin/network/settings.php` where you can enable just registration but not new sites:

[image]

Comment: Thanks toscho ! You are right but I mean everybody can register without my permission but not allowed to make blogs . The choice you selected means I should add new users . At least I think so ! Is it right ?

Comment: Maybe I should set the default role to simple user !

Comment: Oh, I thought you did that already. :)

Comment: So what should I do now ?